# Get Products in Category WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to pull all products located within a certain category slug.

I've tried the following, however both return every product in the store.

```
$products = wc_get_products( array( 'category' => array( 'Sony' ) ));
```

and

```
$productlist = wp_query(array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'product_cat' => 'Sony'));
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: use category_slug not category name. 

Try
`$products = wc_get_products( array( 'category' => array( 'sony' ) ));`

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference.

Would I be correct to assume that 'Sony' vs 'sony' should return no products at all given there is no 'Sony' slug?

Comment: @CitrisLemon `$products = wc_get_products( array( 'category' => array( 'sony' ) )); //With slug` this seems to be working, can you share whole code to identify the problem properly and help you for the same,Thank you!

Comment: Ended up figuring out the problem. Wasn't related to that code, thanks a lot everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'product',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'tax_query'      => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms'    => 12,// category ID
    ),
),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'product_cat' => 'Sony', 'orderby' => 'rand' );
    $data = new WP_Query( $args );
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this and replace ENTER_CATEGORY with slug name or use simple 'terms' => 'slug/categoryname'

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'             => 'product',
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'tax_query'             => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
                'terms'         => array_map( 'sanitize_title', explode( ',', 'ENTER_CATEGORY' ) ),
                'field'         => 'slug',
                'operator'      => $atts['operator']
            )
        )
    );
```